# Find the coefficient which can minimize the difference between Y and one X

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

I only have one variable `Y` which contains roughly 100 numbers in it, and there is a `X` has the same length as `Y`. Then, we use take the `sum(Y)` and `sum(X)`.

Distance is defined as the difference between aX and Y, so simply make `ax-Y` close to 0. To make some clarifications, `a` is a number, `X` and `Y` are vectors with same length. The goal is to find an `a` such that `aX`= `Y`.

Here is my code:

```
lst =c()
for(a in seq(0.1,1,0.001)){
  a = c(sum(a * X)- sum(Y))
  lst = c(lst,a)
}

min(abs(lst)) #I only get the minimum, but I don't know how to get the correspond `a`
```

**a is just a number, not like `X` and `Y` who have length equals to 100**

Comment: By "distance", do you mean the Euclidean distance? If so, this is simply linear regression without an intercept, which minimizes precisely this. Or do you have another distance measure in mind, perhaps the mean absolute difference?

Comment: How are you defining distance between two variables? Unless you tell us that, it is not clear what approach might be used.

Comment: I edit my questions.

Comment: Re "close to 0:" The "0" in that phrase is a vector with 100 components.  You need to tell us how to measure how "close to 0" such a vector might be.  There are a huge number of options, depending on your application.

Comment: I make another edit, hope it helps.

Comment: Your code tries to find the value $a = \sum_i Y_i / \sum_j X_j.$  It's not useful for solving this kind of problem, because the difference between sums of components is not a distance at all.

Answer (score 1):

$aX - Y = 0$ only for $X = Y/a$, in which case finding the value would be trivial since you can use basic arithmetic for that.

When there is no [linear relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) between the two variables, or their relationship is noisy

$$
Y = aX + \varepsilon
$$

where $\varepsilon$ is a random noise term, this is not that simple. In such a case, what you are trying to achieve is to find such $a$ that minimizes some [distance $d$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) between the points. Since you have vectors, you would be minimizing a cost function that aggregates the distances between the points $c(aX,\,Y) = \sum_i d(aX_i,\,Y_i)$

$$
\operatorname{arg\,min}_a \,c(aX,\,Y)
$$

One of the most important properties of the distance function is that it decreases when the two values get closer to each other. Notice that $ax - y$ *is not* a valid distance, as it doesn't have this property (think of what happens when $ax$ is bigger vs smaller than $y$). Valid cost function could be something like a sum of squared errors $\sum_i (aX_i - Y_i)^2$, or sum of absolute errors $\sum_i |aX_i - Y_i|$, etc.

Squared error is the [most popular one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274650/what-makes-mean-square-error-so-good), and the problem described above under this error is just [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function). In the [univariate case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression), it doesn't even need any complicated maths to solve. For other distance functions, you will need an [optimization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), many of which are commonly implemented in scientific software (e.g. R's [`optimize`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optimize) or [`optim`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optim) functions). Your code uses [brute-force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) which is the most trivial, but also an inefficient (both in terms of quality of the results and speed) algorithm. "Which algorithm" is problem specific. For trivial problems like the one described above (absolute error, one parameter), you can safely stick to the ones provided by R with their default settings.

Comment: This is a confusing post, because it consistently fails to distinguish *vectors* like $aX-Y$ from *real numbers,* which is what any distance must be, by definition.

Comment: I think this is what I want to say! An optimization algorithm, but I don't know which algorithm.

Comment: @whuber I didn't want to overload it with terminology, but made some improvements.

Comment: It depends on the metric $d.$  This is a *very simple* problem because you are varying a single real value $a.$ However, some metrics (such as the maximum absolute distance, known as $L^\infty$) lead to nondifferentiable functions.  Thus, the choice of algorithm depends on the metric, *which is why we keep asking you to tell us what metric you need.*  @Tim This isn't a matter of terminology.  When you make it look like a vector is a number, you're going to confuse anyone who reads your answer.